# mongodb one to many relationship db keeps adding same character to the account

Tags: javascript, mongodb, relational-database, one-to-many

my mongodb keeps adding the same user to the account->characters array

tried finding by different id making sure that that character doesnt exist already

```
    for (const {account, character, dead, online, rank} of apiResponse.data.entries) {
      const poeDbCharacter = await PoeCharacter.findOneAndUpdate({character_name: character.name}, {
        $set: {
          character_id: character.id,
          character_name: character.name,
          level: character.level,
          class: character.class,
          experience: character.experience,
          dead: dead,
          online: online,
          rank: rank,
          league: leagues[currentLeague]
        }
      }, {upsert: true, new: true, useFindAndModify: false});

      await PoeAccount.findOneAndUpdate({name: account.name}, {
        $set: {
          name: account.name,
          realm: account.realm,
          challenges: account.challenges.total,
          twitch: ('twitch' in account) ? account.twitch.name : null,

        },
        $push: {character: poeDbCharacter._id}
      }, {upsert: true, new: true, useFindAndModify: false});
    }

    (currentLeague === (leagues.length - 1 )) ? currentLeague = 0 : currentLeague++;
```

i want to make it so that every account can have multiple character but they have to be unique

is that event possible with this setup i'm currently trieing?